# Dask map_partitions fails when dataframe contains date field

Tags: python, pandas, dask

The following code fails, saying that field `date2` doesn't have the `month` attribute because `date2` type is `Series`, when its type is clearly a date. What am I missing?

Error is `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'month'`

```
import pandas as pd
import dask
import dask.dataframe as dd
import datetime

pdf = pd.DataFrame({
    'id2': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2],
    'balance': [150, 140, 130, 280, 260],
    'date2' : [datetime.datetime(2021,3,1), datetime.datetime(2021,4,1), 
               datetime.datetime(2021,5,1), datetime.datetime(2021,1,1), 
               datetime.datetime(2021,2,1)]
})

ddf = dd.from_pandas(pdf, npartitions=1) 

def func2(df):
    return df.date2.month

x = ddf.map_partitions(func2)  # <-- fails here
```

Comment: Not too familiar with dask, but if it mirrors pandas api - then it should be `df.date2.dt.month`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access `datetime` functions, one needs to use [`.dt` accessor](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html), so the fix in this case is:

```py
def func2(df):
    return df.date2.dt.month
```

Note that in this case, the function accepts a dataframe, but returns a series. This is fine, but for some use-cases one might be interested in modifying the dataframe and returning the modified version. In such cases, the function would look like this:

```py
def func2(df):
    df['modified_column'] = df.date2.dt.month
    return df
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that pandas' accessors are supported in dask, so you don't need the mapping function at all in this case

```
x = ddf.date2.dt.month
```

(this is also stated in a comment)